# When does Google require re-authentication?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a script that sends an email whenever a user submits a form. Since the script is using my Google account to send the emails, I have to authorize it and that makes sense. However, my scripts eventually stop working (seemingly)randomly and requires re-authentication. The most recent occurrence happened today, one of my scripts requires authentication even though it states that the last edit happened 4 days ago.

Basically, I understand why I have to authenticate, but what makes me have to re-authenticate?

Comment: Did you make any changes (even the slightest) to your script?

Comment: Yes I did Serge but it seems to let some changes slide by without authentication. I thought that maybe that was something Google did so that you could test small changes without having to re-authenticate every two seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to the script will require you to re-authorize. And something as simple as adding a space to your code counts as a change. Many times these are inadvertent.

Comment: That's what I assumed but it seems like sometimes it makes me re-authenticate and sometimes it does not. Also I noticed that there were multiple viewers on the form, all of which were my same account. Maybe that has something to do with the inconsistency. I will check. Thank you for the clarification though.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts that use more sensitive apis like Gmail will force a reauth on every code change. Otherwise, you shouldn't need a reauth unless you use a new api, or if you start writing when in the past you were only reading (basically, if you do something beyond the scope of what was previously authorized).