# Deploying webapp authorization policy

Tags: web-applications, permissions, google-apps-script, authorize

I have a webapp script which access some resources that requires the user's authorize.
I update this script on short circles and noticed that after few deployments, users are getting the authorize request again, even thought there was no change in the resources needed for the script to run(text change for example).

Couldn't find the policy about the authorize requests , hope you could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See Corey's answer i[n this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354602/when-does-google-require-re-authentication), some service calls need re-authorization even when small changes are made.